# SpringBoot Log4j2 JMS Appender -> "JMS message Producer Not Available"

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic, log4j2

I have a SpringBoot App I am trying to implement log4j2's JMS Appender.
The app seems to find the appender but then I get an error:

```
JMS message Producer Not Available
```

I have declared a bean of return type `org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory` and defined the appender and logger in my `log4j2.xml` (the logger works fine to a RollingFile and Console).

I am unsure how to resolve this and can't find much on Google.

`log4j2.xml` appender entry:

```xml
<JMS name="jmsQueue" 
     destinationBindingName="logQueue"
     factoryBindingName="com.mydomain.developer.myappname.ActiveMQ.MyQueueConnectionFactory"
     factoryName="org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory"
     providerURL="tcp://localhost:61616"
     userName="admin"
     password="admin" >
    <JsonLayout properties="true"/>
</JMS>
```

My Bean:

```java
package com.mydomain.developer.myappname.ActiveMQ

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyQueueConnectionFactory{

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory loggingConnectionFactory(){
        return new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("admin","admin","tcp://localhost:61616");
    }
}
```

StackTrace:

```
2018-12-14 12:29:47,421 main ERROR An exception occurred processing Appender jmsQueue org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Error sending to JMS Manager 'jmsQueue': JMS message producer not available
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.mom.JmsManager.send(JmsManager.java:458)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.mom.JmsAppender.append(JmsAppender.java:269)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:156)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:129)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:120)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:84)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:464)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:448)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:431)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:406)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:63)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.logMessage(Logger.java:146)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2170)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:2125)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2108)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2007)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1866)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog.log(LogAdapter.java:241)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog.info(LogAdapter.java:205)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker.postProcessAfterInitialization(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:330)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:434)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:392)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:91)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:109)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:253)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1091)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:240)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at ms.allstar.developer.fibresendinboxmessagerequest.FibreSendInboxMessageRequestApplication.main(FibreSendInboxMessageRequestApplication.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:558)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 2):

As the [Log4j documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#JMSAppender) makes clear, the `factoryBindingName` in the JMS appender configuration does *not* refer to a Spring bean. It refers to a JNDI name where the connection factory is bound.

Try using a configuration like this:

```xml
<JMS name="jmsQueue" 
     destinationBindingName="dynamicQueues/logQueue"
     factoryBindingName="ConnectionFactory"
     factoryName="org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory"
     providerURL="tcp://localhost:61616"
     userName="admin"
     password="admin">
    <JsonLayout properties="true"/>
</JMS>
```

To be clear, the ActiveMQ `InitialContextFactory` implementation is client-side only meaning it doesn't actually connect across the network to "look up" resources on a remote server. Instead all the resources are typically configured in the "environment" properties of the `InitialContext`. However, there is a default JMS connection factory bound by default to `ConnectionFactory` and the `dynamicQueues/` prefix can be used on any queue name if you don't want to or can't specifically configure it. I recommend you use these default resources for convenience and simplicity.

Answer (score -1):

Based on ActiveMQ documentation (Visit https://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-log4j-jms-appender-with-activemq) you must create new file: *jndi.properties*. 
Then add one line:

```
queue.logQueue=myQueueToLogEvents
```

Notice, that

```
logQueue
```

is name from your *log4j2.xml* file, and

```
myQueueToLogEvents
```

is name of destination queue. Finally message will be send to *myQueueToLogEvents* queue.
I hope it helps.