# Configuration application logs into ActiveMQ with log4j2 failure

Tags: java, xml, jms, activemq-classic, log4j2

So I'm trying to follow this tutorial:
https://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-log4j-jms-appender-with-activemq
of logging my application's logs into a queue I created in ActiveMQ.

The goal is pretty simple, I just want to configure my logger to log straight to the queue with the JMS appender.

This is my Main class for testing:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
        logger.error("Test.");

    }
}
```

log4j.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="Main">
  <Appenders>
    <JMS name="jmsQueue" destinationBindingName="MyQueue"
        factoryName="org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory"
        factoryBindingName="ConnectionFactory"> 
      <JsonLayout properties="true"/>
    </JMS>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="jmsQueue"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

jndi.properties file:

```
queue.MyQueue=MyQueue

java.naming.factory.initial = org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory

# use the following property to configure the default connector
java.naming.provider.url = https://localhost:8161

# use the following property to specify the JNDI name the connection factory
# should appear as. 
#connectionFactoryNames = connectionFactory, queueConnectionFactory, topicConnectionFactry

# register some queues in JNDI using the form
# queue.[jndiName] = [physicalName]
queue.MyQueue = MyQueue


# use the following property to specify the JNDI name the connection factory
# should appear as.
connectionFactoryNames = connectionFactory
```

While trying to run the code I'm getting:

```
2020-01-18 17:31:44,592 main WARN The JNDI InitialContextFactory class name [org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory] was provided, but there was no associated provider URL. This is likely to cause problems.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
2020-01-18 17:31:49,638 main ERROR An exception occurred processing Appender jmsQueue org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Error sending to JMS Manager 'jmsQueue': JMS message producer not available
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.mom.JmsManager.send(JmsManager.java:455)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.mom.JmsAppender.append(JmsAppender.java:251)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:156)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:129)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:120)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:84)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:543)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:502)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:485)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:460)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:82)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.log(Logger.java:161)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2198)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:2152)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2135)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2011)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1983)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.error(AbstractLogger.java:740)
    at com.noamg.Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

I was trying to give the jndi a associated provider URL but without any luck.

Someone maybe has a clue how to configure it properly? I don't think it should be that hard... I probably missing something...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few differences between what you've configured and what the documentation you cited outlines. You've created a `jndi.properties` file where the documentation doesn't list that at all, and you're using Log4j 2.x where the documentation is using Log4j 1.2.x so basically all the appender configuration in the documentation is worthless for your needs.

All the JNDI configuration is possible through the appender itself so there's no need for a `jndi.properties` file.

The `WARN` message indicates a problem with your appender configuration:

```
WARN The JNDI InitialContextFactory class name [org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory] was provided, but there was no associated provider URL. This is likely to cause problems.
```

Therefore you need to configure a provider URL on your appender.

Also, you're using `https://localhost:8161` for the provider URL in `jndi.properties` but port `8161` by default is the *HTTP* port which won't work with the OpenWire JMS client you're trying to use. You should almost certainly be using port `61616` with the `tcp` URL scheme.

The ActiveMQ `InitialContextFactory` implementation is client-side only meaning it doesn't actually connect across the network to "look up" resources on a remote server. Instead all the resources are typically configured in the "environment" properties of the `InitialContext`. However, there is a default JMS connection factory bound by default to `ConnectionFactory` and the `dynamicQueues/` prefix can be used on any queue name if you don't want to or can't specifically configure it.

Therefore, I recommend you eliminate the `jndi.properties` file and use this appender configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="Main">
  <Appenders>
    <JMS name="jmsQueue" destinationBindingName="dynamicQueues/MyQueue"
        factoryName="org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory"
        factoryBindingName="ConnectionFactory" providerURL="tcp://localhost:61616"> 
      <JsonLayout properties="true"/>
    </JMS>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="jmsQueue"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Hey, hanks for the help.
I have changed to everything you've said but I am still getting the "Error sending to JMS Manager 'jmsQueue': JMS message producer not available" error message.
The reason I made the jndi.properties file was because of this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779984/springboot-log4j2-jms-appender-jms-message-producer-not-available
which has the same error.
Maybe do you know why it's not finding the provider?
Thanks!

Comment: Try prefixing the `destinationBindingName` with `dynamicQueues/`. I updated my answer to reflect this change.

Comment: Did you try the change I suggested in my previous comment? If so, did it work? Thanks!

Comment: Oh hey,
Sorry for the delayed response, no. It didn't work. I had some other things going on so I just switched to a rolling file logging procedure. I am planning on getting back to it soon. But the the bottom line, it still didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: I just tried this out for myself in a simple project, and I found a configuration error. My `providerURL` was using `https` by mistake (leftover from your original configuration). I've corrected it to use `tcp` instead, and now everything is working as expected. I updated my answer with this change.